# JSP Portlet not submitting form values

Tags: null, portlet, liferay, parameters

I am using Liferay portal 5.x.
I have deployed a simple portlet ( uses jsp & servlet extending GenericPortlet).
This portlet will contain username & password field. I am able to see the form in view mode.
But when  i submit the form, the action is coming to processAction() of the Portlet class but the username & password request parameters are getting as null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Is this a JSR 168 or 286 portlet?

It sounds like you're confident that the `processAction()` method is actually being invoked.  If not, I'd start by verifying that.  The key there would be the action attribute on your form.  Are you using the actionURL tag to render the action attribute on the JSP?

That said, whenever I find calls to `getParameter()` returning null, it means I've misspelled the parameter, either in the name attribute on the input element in the form, or in the argument to `getParameter()`.  Also, the parameters are case sensitive.

Any chance you could update your question with the code for the form and the `processAction()` method?

Here is an example portlet(JSR 286) that pulls the request parameters (package statement and imports omitted):

```java
public class TestPortlet extends GenericPortlet {

public void init() throws PortletException {
    super.init();
}


public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType(request.getResponseContentType());
    PortletRequestDispatcher rd = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/view.jsp");
    rd.include(request,response);
}


public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws PortletException {
    System.err.println(request.getParameter("username"));
    System.err.println(request.getParameter("password"));
}

}
```

Here is a sample JSP:

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<div>
    <form action="<portlet:actionURL />">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                User Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="password" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>                                                
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>                                            
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is I am using JSR 168?

Answer (score 0):

We should add  as a prefix of name.

```
<input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace/>username">
```

Comment: I used the code above but it still does not work, am using JSR 168

Answer (score 0):

Adding namespace for every attribute is troublesome. Another solution to avoid namespacing your parameters is by setting the property requires-namespaced-parameters to false in the liferay-portlet.xml

```
<portlet>
        <portlet-name>portlet-name</portlet-name>
        <icon>/icon.png</icon>
        <!-- Set this property to false to avoid namespacing parameters -->
        <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
        <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
        <css-class-wrapper>portlet-name-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
</portlet>
```